# Centering an element with an adjacent element

Tags: html, css

I basically have a button that I need to align center. Next to that button I need to display something (a checkmark for example). I have been trying to do this but have run into a problem that:
1) if i use display:inline I can't center it
2) if i use display:block I can't add another element next to it

I have been trying to figure it out with display:inline-block to no avail

JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2x5a5zdx/

code:

```
<input  type="button" class='btn btn-md btn-primary' value="Submit Responses" id="submitBttn"/>
    <span class="green-success" id="surveySuccess" >&#10004</span>
    <span class="red-danger" id="surveyFailure" >&#10006</span>
```

And then the css

```
#submitBttn {
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
}

#surveySuccess, #surveyFailure {

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out, `margin: auto` will not center an `inline` element.

Since `inline`/`inline-block` level elements respect the [`text-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), you could simply add `text-align: center` to the parent element. In doing so, the children elements will be centered since they are `inline` by default.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/L9mr3xbb/)

```
.parent-element {
    text-align: center;
}
.parent-element > span,
.parent-element > input {
    display: inline-block;   /* Added for example purposes */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Alternatively, [in supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you could also [utilize flexbox layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and set the `display` of the parent element to `flex` and add `justify-content: center` for horizontal centering:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/81rn4dj2/)

```
.parent-element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fiddle still center aligns everything https://jsfiddle.net/r8cy9xk8/2/

Comment: @pasquers Even though you set the `display` to `block`, the text will still be centered since it respects the `text-align` property. Notice what happens when you set the `display` of *all* the children elements to `block` - [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3guen38h/) - notice that only the text is centered?

Answer (score 1):

To display the button and icons horizontally centered on the page, wrap them both in a div and set it's text-align property to center.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input  type="button" class='btn btn-md btn-primary' value="Submit Responses" id="submitBttn"/>
    <span class="green-success" id="surveySuccess" >&#10004</span>
    <span class="red-danger" id="surveyFailure" >&#10006</span>
</div>

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic**

If you want to center the button and the checks together, as a whole, centering is simple. You just need to add `text-align: center` to the parent element (which you may have to introduce).

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" class='btn btn-md btn-primary' value="Submit Responses" id="submitBttn" />
  <span class="green-success" id="surveySuccess">&#10004</span>
  <span class="red-danger" id="surveyFailure">&#10006 This content <i>does</i> affect centering.</span>
</div>
```

Or, if you want the button itself to be centered, regardless of the labels, you can use `position: absolute` to pull the labels out of the flow. This is especially useful if you want to display only one label at a time. If you display both, they will be on top of each other, so you'd have to solve that.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#surveySuccess, #surveyFailure {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#surveyFailure {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" class='btn btn-md btn-primary' value="Submit Responses" id="submitBttn" />
  <span class="green-success" id="surveySuccess">&#10004 Button is not moved</span>
  <span class="red-danger" id="surveyFailure">&#10006 Button is not moved</span>
</div>
```

Personally, I'd like to show labels like that through CSS mainly, so this code is slightly altered again, adding a feedback text in the span (if you like), but adding the check or cross (and color too) in CSS by setting a class of the span. By simply adding the class `success` or `failure` you can change the way symbol and the color of the single 'surveyResult' span you have now:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#surveyResult {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#surveyResult.success {
  color: green;
}
#surveyResult.success::before {
  /* \2714 is the CSS (hexadecimal) notation of &#10004; */
  content: '\2714 ';
}

#surveyResult.failure {
  color: red;
}
#surveyResult.failure::before {
  content: '\2716 ';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" class='btn btn-md btn-primary' value="Submit Responses" id="submitBttn" />
  <span class="success" id="surveyResult">You did great!</span>
</div>
```